# ISP name in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android and currently developing an android application, and I got to a point where I need to find the ISP name when the phone is connected to a wifi access point, there is no function in Android to do it (like the one to get the operator name, already implemented in Android).
Can anyone help me? Share his function or give me a solution on how to do it? 
Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know if there is a function for that. In case it doesn't, I suppose the phone could try making an http request like this one: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Answer (score 0):

PeeHaa is right there is no direct method of getting the isp..

Case A is you are directly on mobile network
Case b is you are on wifi
Case c is you are on ththering

In all cases you can use the util lib to get the IP

```
Utils.getIPAddress(true);
```

The submit it to a php script like this

```
<?php
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url=file_get_contents("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/$ip");
preg_match_all('/<th>(.*?)<\/th><td>(.*?)<\/td>/s',$url,$output,PREG_SET_ORDER);
$isp=$output[1][2];
$city=$output[9][2];
$state=$output[8][2];
$zipcode=$output[12][2];
$country=$output[7][2];
?>
```

YOu may use any isp db provide api you want this is just an example..The process will be to get the ip and then submit it to the php script via http and return all the above values..A long process but effective..It will however lag if you have too many request, depends on the api server...happy coding...